# iOS Prevent Position Fixed Element from Zooming

Tags: css, ios, zooming, responsive-design, css-position

I have a responsive site that has a position: fixed; header > nav

I want the user to be able to zoom into the content of the page while leaving the position: fixed; element alone. Is this possible?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I'm looking for the exact same thing.

Comment: Sadly, no, I have not found a solution for this. If I ever do, I will be sure to update this question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I would go about it using Jquery. There are many responsive scripts that accomplish what I think you are trying to accomplish. Try Zoomooz.js. You can find it on Github or the authors site.

```
anne.aukia.com/zoomooz/
github.com/jaukia/zoomooz/zipball/master
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Potentially, Zoomooz could work, but this isn't really the solution I am looking for. I want to retain the natural zooming of the iOS while keeping my position: fixed; element unzoomable. So, when the user zooms in with their fingers, all the content zooms, but my fixed header stays the same size. Thanks for the suggestion though, this looks like a useful plugin.

Comment: sorry I couldn't be of greater help.